# Monitoring RAM usage in android

Tags: android, ram

I'm trying to limit RAM usage of my android application and I'd like to get via code the same value android shows in the Active Applications list. I've tried the Debug class and Debug.MemoryInfo object but I don't know what is the RAM value I mentioned before. Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: I'd focus more on **`adb shell dumpsys procrank`** (Android 4.4+) and **`adb shell dumpsys meminfo`**. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: Yes I've already checked out this page but what I want as I said before is that specific RAM value, I don't know what to do with all those values